# Rails Routing Incorrectly links to show.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails and have encountered some behavior I don't understand. I'm trying to create a simple CRUD app. On the 'new' view after data entry fields and submit button I am trying to add a link that will go to another page (I'll call it 'fnord').

Instead of linking to fnord, it's going to show.html. Given that rails is convention based I wonder if this is a default behavior of some kind, but I haven't been able to figure out what triggers it or the proper way of routing to fnord.

This is Rails 3.2.21, Ruby 1.9.3. I originally generated the model, views and controller using scaffold and then started tweaking things.

Here's my controller (minus unrelated actions - index, destroy, etc):

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController 
  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @employee }
    end
  end

  def new
    @employee = Employee.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @employee }
    end
  end

  def fnord
    #nothing yet - just trying to get the page to appear right now
  end
```

Here's the relevant code from new.html.erb:

```
<h2>New Employee</h2>
<%= render 'form' %>

<!-- content, data entry fields, submit button, etc -->

<div>
  <%= link_to 'Fnord', employees_fnord_path %>
<div/>
```

Here's the view, fnord.hmtl.erb:

```
<h2>Fnord</h2>
<br/>
<p>this is fnord.html</p>
```

Here's my routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :employees  
  get 'employees/fnord'
  root :to => 'employees#new'  
end
```

I ran 'rake routes' and get the following output:

```
       employees GET    /employees(.:format)          employees#index
                 POST   /employees(.:format)          employees#create
    new_employee GET    /employees/new(.:format)      employees#new
   edit_employee GET    /employees/:id/edit(.:format) employees#edit
        employee GET    /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#show
                 PUT    /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#update
                 DELETE /employees/:id(.:format)      employees#destroy
 employees_fnord GET    /employees/fnord(.:format)    employees#fnord
            root        /                             employees#new
```

As far as I can see this all looks right, but when I click on the link in new.html it returns show.html, not fnord.html.

The url that shows up in the browser is even locahost:3000/employees/fnord, but the content is from show.html.

I read the routing documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but  didn't see any explanations.

I've tried restarting rails (many times) and clearing my browser cache as well and those steps didn't help.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the `/employees/fnord` route supposed to be specific to an employee? e.g. do you want the route to be: `/employees/:id/fnord`?  Also, when you click the link what do you see in the browser's web inspector? The fact that it routes you to the `show` route kind of makes it sound like a new employee is being POST'd to the server (the result of creating a new resource is to render the show page).

Comment: No, fnord is not specific to one employee. I checked the header and it is a GET request:
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/employees/fnord
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Comment: I also get back show.html even if I just enter http://localhost:3000/employees/fnord in the browser. Really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route for `/employees/fnord` matches the `show` route because the show route is looking for URL's in the format: `/employees/:id`

When you go to `/employees/fnord` it interprets `fnord` as the ID of some employee, and it routes it to the `show` method.

One way to fix it is to declare the `/employees/fnord` route before the resources routes, so that it matches first:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'employees/fnord'
  resources :employees  
  root :to => 'employees#new'  
end
```

Another way is to simply change the name of the URL so that it doesn't match the pattern of `/employees/:id`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :employees  
  get 'employees1/fnord', to: 'employees#fnord'
  # or whatever
  get 'foo', to: 'employees#fnord'
  # etc...
  get 'employees/foo/fnord', to: 'employees#fnord'
  root :to => 'employees#new'  
end
```

Comment: BOOM. That was it. I understand now. I went with your first suggestion since it was easier, but I understand what you're talking about with the second option. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To add to pattern matching, if you're sticking to the convention over configuration approach, your `id` is probably a number, so you can route based on that `resources :employees, id: /\d+/`